# After updating overriding template doesn't work FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

After updating overriding template doesn't work.

I have done like this and it used to work well.

[Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Templates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html)

However after a few months and I updated the composer/vendor directory , it doesnt' override anymore.

I don't alter the code when updating vendor directory.

I am using fosuserbundle 'dev-master', does anyone know the reason??

Comment: What is the Symfony version are you installed? Which of the two methods are you using to overwrite the template?

Comment: I use method B and my symfony version is 2.8.14 , FOSUserbundle is dev-master.. I will try to change or downgrade the version...